# NullPointerException while mocking a class with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

While trying to test a method with Junit and Mockito2 , I am getting NullPointerException .

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
    Application app=mock(Application.class);//line 2
    assertEquals(true,app.methodToTest());
    }
```

I am getting a NullPointerException on line 2 .   I am using junit 4.8.1 and mockito-all 2.0.2-beta .The Application class has constructor with Argument `JSONObject(org.json.JSONObject)`

Comment: do you have any setup related code? Have you imported the right `mock` method? Share the complete stack trace

Comment: You have to injectMock the Application class, since your are writting the test cases of Application class and then Mock dependent services of class. Other thing you should have setup or initialize Mockito. Provide the Application class content for better clarity.

Comment: @sidgate   Updated the code with  relevant imports .I don't have any setup related code.

Comment: as @krishnaPrasad has mentioned I think it requires a class on top of it. Also make sure that the tests package has the access to the Application layer

Comment: Are you having any `@RunWith` on your test class?

Comment: Seems you are keeping out some important piece of information. Can you reproduce the issue with minimal code and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

Before writing any test cases for methods you have to initialized `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` e.g:

```
protected boolean mockInitialized = false;
@Before
public void setUp() {
   if (!mockInitialized) {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      mockInitialized = true;
   }
}
```

Hope this may resolve your issue. or provide the actual class code for which you are trying to write test cases.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` is only necessary when you declare your mocks using the @Mock annotation.  In the question above, that is not the case.  The user is explicitly creating the mock by calling `Mockito.mock()`

Answer (score 0):

As I was thinking , the nullpointerexception was due to  mismatches in dependencies .
The mentioned issue got resolved by using below dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4-legacy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4-legacy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```